# How to pass routeProvider attributes to controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, route-provider

I need to setup a controller with some data passed from the routeProvider.

I would like the value topic to be passed to my controller VideoCtrl and then assigned to a value such as video.topic

```
  $routeProvider
    .when('/video/:topic', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/video/video-page.tmpl.html',
        controller: 'VideoCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'video'       
    });
```

It seems like I should just need to call $routeProvider in my controller function:

```
app.controller('VideoCtrl', function($routeProvider) {
    var video = this;
    video.topic = $routeProvider.topic; // What do I need to add here?
    ...
});
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to inject $routeProvider into the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you need to pass the $routeParams as controller parameter and then you will able to get the passed route value.

```
app.controller('VideoCtrl', function($routeParams) {
    var video = this;
    video.topic = $routeParams.topic; 
    ...
});
```